# spring security securitycotextholder cannot save authentication to securitycotextholder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm new to Spring Boot so please forgive me if I use something wrong or a wrong term.

The jwt generator filter defines Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() as null, which is really starting to confuse me a lot.

When I examined the BasicAuthentication filter, I saw that it gave null when converting the incoming request value to authentication in the BasicAuthentication filter, I could not fully understand what my mistake was here.

The reason why I write /login as a separate endpoint is that I don't get a 401 error when I send a request to the default login endpoint in spring security. In general, I have two questions, how can I use this data in BasicAuthenticationFilter and save it in SecurityContextHolder and secondly how can I send a request to the default login endpoint Thank you in advance for your answers

**I have a jwt generator filter like this**

```
public class JwtGeneratorFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null) {
            SecretKey secretKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(SecurityConstants.JWT_KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            String jwt = Jwts.builder().setIssuer("Demo App").setSubject("Jwt token").claim("userName", authentication.getName()).setIssuedAt(new Date()).setExpiration(new Date((new Date().getTime() + 30000000))).signWith(secretKey).compact();
            response.setHeader(SecurityConstants.JWT_HEADER, jwt);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

**and I have a security config file like this**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
        config.setMaxAge(3600L);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()));
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()).sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)).authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req.requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        http.addFilterAfter(new JwtGeneratorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

**and I also have a login api like this**

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(@RequestBody User user) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword()));
        return user.toString();

    }
```

***authenticated value in the authentication object returns true but does not generate my jwt token***

**My Solution**

When I examined the BasicAuthentication filter, I saw that it receives authentication in the **header of the request** and **I realized that it has no effect on the filtering process because it is a manual authentication I did here**. If you are a beginner like me, I realized we should send this data (login information) in the header as the default Authentication filter. As far as I understand, for a custom login process, for example, you may be getting too much information, you can write a separate method to determine the login ID and authenticate it through the authentication manager, and if the authentication object received from here is authenticated, it can create a jwt token and return a response back to the end user in this way.

As I said, I just started writing Spring Boot, I apologize if I have any mistakes or mistakes, I stated my own observations and opinions here

Comment: May i ask, if you are new to spring security why did you first thing try to build a custom security solution instead of trying out to implement something that already exists in spring security like basic login or formlogin? As laid out in the official documentation on spring securitys homepage

Comment: because I am developing an application and I needed to use jwt tokens in this application, but I understood why the problem was caused, basically when I examined the process, everything became clearer.

Comment: Also, sending authentication data through the header seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: jwt were never designed to be handed out to browsers, thats why there is no implementation for it in spring security. So what you are building has several security flaws and has some vulnerabilities. JWTs where meant to be used between microservices inside of corporate networks.

Comment: so how can I send the login data to the filters in the request body or is this possible?

Comment: tbh, if you want to get good at Spring Security, i suggest you read https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html and first try to implement FormLogin https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html and look at their example https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/hello-security-explicit/src/main/java/example/SecurityConfiguration.java i cant teach you spring sec in comments.